# Incorporate Commenting in the Hot Questions Algorithm

Tags: discussion, comments, hot-questions

This should be a pretty simple suggestion (although I am not sure how simple it would be to implement).

There are some questions where the question and answers will be the basis of pretty long and active comment threads. I think that this should be used as an indicator of [the Question's Hotness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions).

I would imagine that incorporating it into the Active might not be a good idea, because if I understand correctly, the active list is generated based on whatever made the last contribution, whether it was a question, answer, or edit? Perhaps this should be kept solely for the **HOT** (not Active) calculation.

Comment: "...incorporating it into the Active might **not** be a good idea...", "Perhaps this should be kept solely for the Active calculation."

Comment: Damn it Bill. Why must you be so helpful.

Comment: I was just confused.  Either you'd made a typo, or I had suddenly lost my ability to understand plain English.  Needless to say, I'm relieved it was the former.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definitely wouldn't want to see comments affect the Active page (even though I might be the only one who uses it).  Questions already get bumped in the Active queue for every edit to the question or an answer.  Doing the same for every comment would just increase the noise on the Active tab.  If a comment is particularly insightful, it usually leads to an edit to a question/answer, which is going to get the question bumped anyway.

I agree that comments probably should affect a post's hotness score.

Comment: Agreed. I was about halfway through writing down the question when I remembered that Active gets pushed to the top on every occurrence of an answer or edit. I wouldn't want it to get posted on the Active on commenting either if that mechanism stayed in place.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this would be all that useful on SO/SF/SU... but it would certainly come in handy on MSO!