# When I vote for the question, should it move on the top of question stack?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, question-order

The case is the following:

1) I went to the SU and moved to the last page of the questions list. I selected this old unanswered question from the last page [How can I remote desktop from Windows XP into Windows Vista?](https://superuser.com/questions/6407/how-can-i-remote-desktop-from-windows-xp-into-windows-vista) and voted for it

2) Then I click on Questions tab and checked Hot and Active... It doesn't appear on either of them. And it was not in the Newest too.

So, my question is does Voting for a really old question can bring any attention of community to it?

Or it was initially supposed that only author can reanimate the question (by editing it or assigning a bounty). And also a user with 500 score can retag questions, that seems to be similar to Edit and also will move the question on top of the stack.

What I suppose that Active questions should be ordered, taking into account any kind of activity - comments, voting, putting a favorite start, edit, retag and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual "hot" algorithm is documented here

[What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, voting should **not** move the question to the top of the stack. I'm even on the fence about retagging, but that's another post.

The whole idea behind the front page and the "active" tab in the Questions view is for people to be able to see posts that have recently been created or changed. Voting does not change the question, and therefore should not put the question at the top of the stack. I know that as a user, I would find the front page and active tab much less useful if every vote bumped every question to the top. I think that you'd find that the 'fun' questions that collect upvotes wouldn't ever disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Voting and marking as favorite do not change the actual question/answer. Thus the question is still inactive.