# Non-active edit button

Tags: feature-request, edits, bump, active

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we have the ability to mark a change as minor in questions or answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26483/could-we-have-the-ability-to-mark-a-change-as-minor-in-questions-or-answers)
>   [Can trivial edits not bump the question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107528/can-trivial-edits-not-bump-the-question)

I see that another round of "lets tidy up" has happened, at least around the Perl tag. I'm all for removing "thanks"es and getting the tags correct, but it brings up a wave of old questions that will tempt people into answering. Can't there be a way to say "I'm editing, but leave it inactive"? I propose a button next to `edit` that says, `edit-but-inactive` or some such.

As I type I see that this has been asked in several ways: [Feature request: Trivial-edit checkbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102499/153062) and [Should all answer edits make old questions look "active"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18793/153062) but neither is quite exactly what I'm asking, and the problem keeps popping up.

Comment: Can you clarify what behaviors an "inactive edit" would (or, more likely, would not) have? The typical answer to this in the past has been "some malicious user could check 'do not bump' to secretly introduce spam."

Comment: Today's edits that I'm talking about include:http://stackoverflow.com/posts/895592/revisions, and http://stackoverflow.com/posts/896825/revisions

Comment: In the case of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895592/can-i-have-an-application-scope-variable-in-perl, now that it has popped back up, a newbie might see it and say, hmmm I've been thinking about CGI and now I see CGI::Session, I should try that. The better thing now is to say "don't use CGI".

Answer (score 0):

This circumvents review/quality procedures. I could go vandalize a bunch of old posts and mark them as "trivial", and they wouldn't get noticed (at least not right away). I could go to some very popular questions and edit in ads for my product or blog, mark it as "trivial", and it won't get reviewed until someone happens to notice the edit. In the mean time, a highly viewed, highly voted post will share my spam with everoyne who comes across it.

Comment: Ok, I can see that point, but doesn't this site depend on reputation for moderation? Once you can edit, and you haven't been flagged for spam then is trust there? Alternatively, could some other account have a "mark as inactive" button for when these old threads get tidied to send them back down?

Comment: It only takes 2k rep to edit, but 20k rep to be a "trusted" user...