# Question not appearing among the "top questions"

Tags: support, top-questions

Which are the criteria for questions to appear among the "[top questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)"? (those that you get clicking in the logo)

I used to believe that they were those who recently were created/edited/answered, but now I notice that my last question is not there, despite having being updated 3 minutes ago.

At first I thought it could be because it has a very negative score (-10), but then I noticed there's a question with -7 points (I guess if you filtered out questions with a very negative score, the theresold would have been -5).

What happened then?

**Update**: The -7 points question has been bumped by a moderator, maybe this means that "low-points" questions do actually get filtered, *unless* they are bumped by a moderator?

Comment: kthx###########

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[What Formula Should Be Used To Determine “hot” Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)*

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends what tab you're on. "Top" has a few different dimensions.

And since you asked the threshold to appear on the homepage is -4 on SO/SF/SU and -8 on Meta. Anything lower won't be shown.

Comment: oh lol thanks, I totally missed my guess