# What's the formula used to order the starred chats in chat.meta?

Tags: discussion, chat

The ordering is a function of the age of the chat and the amount of stars. Could the author or somebody on the inside explain the exact formula?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions - we use the same thing, pretty much

Comment: @Marc From that question it isn't clear what is actually implemented. Is it the last formula mentioned in the question? I expect the age is measured in minutes instead of hours in this case.