# Is there a way to see which users's questions are shown most in 'Hot Network Questions' list?

Tags: discussion, support, hot-questions

Is there a way to see which users over the whole Stack Exchange network have the most questions show up on the 'Hot Network Questions' list?

Comment: No.​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Considering hotness [is not recorded](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117792/152859), such thing is not possible. You'll have to keep track yourself if you want it.

Comment: @TheGuy I thought there was a character limit for comments how are you able to do that?

Comment: @Mhmd [Hax](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment409884_3122)

Comment: @Shadow *four years later ...*

Answer (score 2):

### No.

There's [no archive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117792/278659) even of which *questions* have been in the HNQ list, let alone who the OPs were for those questions. It doesn't seem very feasible to keep track of manually either. Historical information on Hot Network Questions is notoriously hard to get.

<sub><sub>This question was answered in comments four years ago, but I thought we might as well give it an actual answer...</sub></sub>

Comment: Well, we can always hope there's some hidden way only SE staff know and might share one day. :)

Comment: @Shadow Quick, let's ask Catija before she signs the non-disclosure agreement!