# How do I view "Hot Network Question" history associated with a given account?

Tags: support, data-explorer, user-accounts, hot-questions

I have asked a lot of questions that made it to "Hot Network Question" list across multiple websites in the Stack Exchange Network, and I need a list of all questions posted by me that had once became "Hot Network Question", for my autobiographical blog posts.

I am wondering if there is a way to get it, preferably programmatically, I mainly use Python by the way.

Currently I only know about if a question has made it into "Hot Network Question" list, there will be "Became Hot Network Question" text in its edit history, so I can write a scrapper right now to view all questions asked by all my accounts and check their edit history to see whether or not that particular string can be found in the history, but I have many accounts and asked many more questions, and this method is very inefficient.

So is there a way I can query that data? I tried to Google search this and it proved futile, and as you know I have not yet gained 25k reputation in any of the sites, so I can't access site analytics, yet...

Is there another way? Please help me.

Comment: It would be nice if we gave out a platinum or diamond badges with each Hot Network Question, and then we could trade them all in at a merchant for a new wizard robe. If you didn't want to trade them in, this would also provide some lasting evidence of your success in that area of the game.

Comment: @EvanCarroll It seems that such suggestion was posted here in the past: [Badge Request: Hotshot (Ask a Hot Network Question)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298861).

Comment: @Martin That's only part of the request. That request is for one badge, but no where in that request does it introduce the concept of in-game merchants, and robes that can be purchased within the free-to-play version of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither of the things I mention are probably directly what you want, but I suppose they are at least worth mentioning.

---

rene created the site [SE HNQ Feeds for Chat](https://lackadaisical-appeal.glitch.me/). It is mentioned, for example, in this answer: [How can I add Hot Network Questions (HNQ) to a chat room feed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313353#314073) You can have a look what things are provided there - or you can contact him directly. (In the [SEDE chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1223/2022/6/16) rene mentioned that this app [does not return all hot network questions](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9234510#9234510).)

---

I'll mention a chatroom [with a feed of HNQs](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89485/hot-network-questions). You could try to [search for your username](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?room=89485&q=%CE%9E%CE%AD%CE%BD%CE%B7+%CE%93%CE%AE%CE%B9%CE%BD%CE%BF%CF%82) or something else that could identify your posts. (This is not very reliable - but still it was worth mentioning, it is a quick way to get at least something. One of possible problems: searching for username won't work if you share the username with other users or if you have different usernames on different sites. Maybe in such cases you might try [searching for your avatar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=fkwKi.jpg&user=&room=89485) or something else.)

---

You could create various queries in [SEDE (Data Explorer)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) which list your hot network questions. Entering HNQ is identified as `PostHistoryTypeId=52` in the `PostHistory` table.

There are certainly many users around who are much more experienced in SQL - but here is what I tried:

- First for a single site: [Hot network questions by a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/1040583/hot-network-questions-by-a-specific-user?userid=234107)
   and a similar query with [more information about the question](https://data.stackexchange.com/codereview/query/1308027/hnqs-posted-by-the-given-user?userid=234107)
- [Hot network questions by a specific user (networkwide)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1605736/hot-network-questions-by-a-specific-user-networkwide?accountid=19871929)
   and [another version](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1605750/hot-network-questions-by-a-specific-user-networkwide?accountid=19871929) - which shows ViewCount, AnswerCount, Score and Tags, too.
- By modifying the query slightly, we can get hot meta posts - the same PostHistoryTypeId is used for them. I will use my account as an example (as I wanted an example where the list is not empty): [Hot meta posts by a specific user (networkwide)](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1605744/hot-meta-posts-by-a-specific-user-networkwide?accountid=267077) and [a more detailed version](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1605755/hot-meta-posts-by-a-specific-user-networkwide?accountid=267077).

To create the multisite query I have [started from the rene's template](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1223?m=8130932#8130932).

I should explicitly mention that entering the HNQ list was added to the revision list in 2019 - so this won't find older HNQs. See: [Now you can know if a question really hit the HNQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/324641), [Please open the Hot Network Questions to auditing via the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286986#324663) and the 2019-02-28 entry in [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59445#322016)

Comment: Might want to exclude meta sites from the network-wide query to avoid counting Hot Meta Posts as Hot Network Questions.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine Thanks, I have missed this problem with the original version of the query. (I have edited it.)

Comment: Two honorable mentions. I'm flattered and get all blurry ;)