# Hot questions lukewarm

Tags: bug, status-completed, hot-questions

Someone took them out of the oven too soon:

[image]

These questions don't look hot at all!

Happens in all browsers; FF 12/13, Chrome Beta/Release, IE8/9

Comment: They're so hot the only numbers that can represent them are all gone, leaving a gaping hole of zeroes

Comment: All that and a bag of Abe Vigoda chips.

Comment: To clarify it looks like the sorting algorithm is working fine; it's just not showing their "hotness" number

Comment: 10:31 PM EST, May 31st: this is still happening.

Comment: 4:09AM PST June 1st, this is still happening

Comment: Pretty sure it's a Build problem at this point, not some server hiccup.

Comment: what exactly does that number represent ? in hot questions?

Comment: @PresleyDias The hover text on the questions on the [hot questions page](http://stackexchange.com/questions) says "*This question has been arbitrarily awarded hotness points.*"  I know, that's quite helpful =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 ok, but what makes a question hot?

Comment: @PresleyDias http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions

Comment: Somehow this feels related to the fact that the front page now shows the most recent question of selected sites instead of the two hottest ones.

Comment: @Toomai hadn't seen that change...not sure if I approve of that or not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Woops, I introduced this bug yesterday when refactoring how we consume our private JSON APIs.

It's fixed now – have your arbitrary *hotness* points back!

Comment: -1 for admitting it was your fault. Don't do that, my manager lurks around MSO, he might get ideas...