# Hot Questions doesn't have weight

Tags: bug, hot-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hot questions lukewarm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134135/hot-questions-lukewarm)

Hot Questions tab shows only 0 for all questions[image]

FF 12, Win 7

Comment: Ah, someone noticed this yesterday, must still be happening: [Hot questions lukewarm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134135/hot-questions-lukewarm)

Comment: Yep, dupe. Appears in all browsers that I can tell; FF13, Chrome Beta and IE8