# Zeros in the "hot questions" popup

Tags: bug, hot-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Hot questions lukewarm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134135/hot-questions-lukewarm)

Am I going mad or did the number of votes used to show next to the questions in the "hot questions" popup?  They're just all zeros now.

[image: all zeros]

EDIT: actually, they're "[hotness points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions)".  But I'm guessing they should not be zeros.

EDIT AGAIN: possibly an implementation of this feature request: [Don't display arbitrary hotness points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101369/dont-display-arbitrary-hotness-points)

Comment: You're right - voted to close.  The amusing title on the original defeated the duplicate-guessing algorithm (and my tired brain)

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the dupe algo seems to ignore the body copy completely