# Case study: Why the huge difference in number of views and upvotes in this case?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, views

We have two very similar questions: One with [A lot of views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033156/how-to-write-ahover-in-inline-css) and other with [Very few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986618/is-it-possible-to-create-inline-pseudo-styles)

I can't understand why this difference of upvotes and views. The second question is more generic, and I find more attractive. So the question is: Why the first one have more views?

I'm not looking for a generic answer - I'm interested in specifics.

Comment: It was probably linked somewhere, that can often generate a lot of traffic and absurdly high vote scores.

Comment: Any way to discover the sites that linked this question?

Comment: The only way to get specifics rather than generic guesses would be if an employee looked up referers. Not sure this is a good use of their time.

Comment: It is a strange thing we can talk about generics like "give keywords that are searched on google" and can't point one keyword in one of these questions - this means that we can't know how to create good questions?

Comment: @fotanus A popular question is not necessarily a good one. Also, what made a popular question popular may have absolutely nothing to do with the question itself. Most questions I've shared around I did so because they had stellar answers.

Comment: It appears the question was indexed by many other sites: http://www.google.co.uk/#q=%22http:%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F1033156%22

Comment: [For a non specific answer see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178277/how-do-some-questions-get-so-many-votes/178278#178278)

Answer (score 2):

When someone searches with **keywords/tags**, then in [Is it possible to create inline pseudo styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986618/is-it-possible-to-create-inline-pseudo-styles) only `CSS` tag is used.

While in other one `HTML` and `inline-style` are also there. So while searching this will be seen on either of the three tags, resulting in a click and one more view count.

And one human behavior is to go with public, they see 80+ votes and shares this question as link to other answers, so this shown up and we go on to see this as well.