# Does accepting an answer affect the question being on a hot network question list directly?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, hot-questions

If a question is currently on a Hot Network List, does accepting one of its answers directly affect whether it's on a hot list later or not?

"directly" means that it affects the "hot" formula computations.

I'm excluding secondary effects here, e.g. if "accepting" affects the number of views, that clearly might affect HNQ placement, but it's **not** a direct effect of the kind I'm asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having an accepted answer does not affect the question being *hot* or not. I am basing this statement as per the following [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11602/) on [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions):

> Note that accepted answers weight not at all in hotness. This is intentional, as I feel accepted answers are a fine social contract, but not a good data point for question or answer quality.