# How are the questions in the "Month" tab selected?

Tags: discussion, questions, homepage

I have noticed the "Month" tab in the top questions page, which from what I assume, is probably the top questions of the month.

The odd thing is that I notice questions with more than 2 down votes, no answers selected, and less than 100 views on the question.

So, how are questions in the "Month" (and "Week") tab selected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see both in the tab button tooltip and the window title when you're at it, this is actually "**Hottest Questions** This Month", meaning they are chosen using the same formula used for the questions in the "Hot" tab which show only questions from last few days.

The formula is displayed in [What formula should be used to determine "hot" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions) and probably didn't change to this day:

```
(log(Qviews)*4) + ((Qanswers * Qscore)/5) + sum(Ascores)
--------------------------------------------------------
((QageInHours+1) - ((QageInHours - Qupdated)/2)) ^ 1.5
```

So the system takes all questions asked in the last 30 days, sorting by the above  formula, then display the top X questions, where X is different among sites. For example. in Stack Overflow it's showing the top 95 questions, here on MSE the top 35.

Note that as also mentioned in the above question, this is **not** the same formula as used for the HNQ (Hot Network Question), which is very different.

Comment: I think you answered only the question title, but the OP is saying in the "month" button there are questions with 2 downvotes, no answers selected, and less than 100 views on the question. How is that possible?

Comment: @Mari-LouA unlike HNQ, there are no filters. All questions are shown, the hotness score matters only for the sort. So with negative score or no answers the question will just have a low score.

Comment: I was going to answer this as well, but I noticed the order of the questions is sometimes different, e.g. the questions here: https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/?tab=month appear in a different order here: https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot. Caching?

Comment: @Glorfindel huh, that's interesting.