# Markdown rendering changed for this quoted bullet list

Tags: bug, markdown

This [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164712/178179) contains some quoted bullet list that used to be better displayed. What happened?

[In 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170117012538/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11602/what-formula-should-be-used-to-determine-hot-questions):

[image]

[Now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164712/178179):

[image]

Comment: It's just been edited now to be fixed. In short, the old renderer only required some lines in a quote to be prefaced by right angle brackets, but the new CommonMark renderer requires all of them to be so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is due to [the CommonMark migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348746/241919) in 2020 and mass-editing for Stack Overflow Blog HTTPS migration in 2021.**

By default, the system tried to migrate all posts to CommonMark without breaking the format, if possible. Otherwise, the system would ignore them to let a human editor fix it manually.

> Things might get funky when you're editing a post that renders differently with the new CommonMark renderer. Again, if we detected that a post would look differently when rendered with the new CommonMark renderer during the migration, we wouldn't save a new version of this post as part of the migration. This way, all posts continue to look the same when being viewed. However, once someone comes in and edits it, it will be rendered using the new CommonMark renderer and this might cause the post to look slightly different than what we had before.

This was the case, as it can be seen on [its revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/164712/revisions) that there's no CommonMark migration between rev. #16 and #17 in 2020.

However, in 2021, the Community bot mass-edited the posts that contain links to the Stack Overflow blog in HTTP to HTTPS. This also re-rendered the current markdown with the new CommonMark engine, where [as Sonic commented it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386046/markdown-rendering-changed-for-this-quoted-bullet-list#comment1287216_386046), CommonMark requires all lines to be prefixed with `>` to be considered a single continuous block, thus the accidental broken formatting.

> **Blockquotes**: Previously, empty lines between two lines marked as blockquotes would make one big blockquote. Moving forward, you'd get two distinct blockquotes this way, unless you start the empty line with a `>` character, too: